# C++ Can you refer to the this pointer in a constructor or a destructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, this, destructor

This is honestly just a general question, I have no code that requires fixing. I'm just curious as to whether or not you can refer to the `this` pointer in a constructor or a destructor.

A small example code would also be appreciated so I may follow along.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constructors and destructors both have access to the `this` pointer as do all other methods, except if they are `static`, (the methods I mean).

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

class C {

public:
    int *a;

    C() {
        std::cout << "calling constructor\n";
        this->a = new int(5);
    }
    ~C() {
        std::cout << "\ncalling destructor";
        delete this->a;
    }
};

int main() {
    
    C c{};
    std::cout << *c.a;
}
```

Output:

```
calling constructor
5
calling destructor
```

This is a simplified version, note that when a class needs a user defined destructor it most likely also needs a user defined copy constructor and a user defined copy assignment operator, as defined in the [rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)).